# What proportion of Vishnu temples do not follow any vaishnavite sampradaya and if they do they don't follow any vaishnavite agamas?

Tags: vaishnavism

We have some Siva Vishnu temples in which both Siva and Vishnu are worshiped.  temples like Sankaranarayanan koil have both deities in the sanctum sanctorum.  In my town at one of the local hindus temples, the main deity is krishna, but there is a Siva linga also and all major Hindu religious festivals like siva ratri are celebrated.

These would be examples that don't belong to any vaishnavite sampradaya, but vishnu or one of his avataras is being worshiped.

Mere co-location of Vishnu with an anya-devata doesn't exclude following vaishnavite sampradaya - at chidambaram govindaraja (vishnu) is co-located with nataraja (Siva) but there ia an old joke that iyengars on entering the temple complex would walk with averted eyes until they come to the vishnu temple, do their worship and walk out with averted eyes.

The second part of the question is not necessarily about anya devatas - the question is whether an agama accepted by vaishnavites is being followed.

Comment: Your title and body aren't matching.  Do you want to know about what percentage of Vishnu temples don't belong to a Vaishnava sect, or do you want to know what percentage of Vishnu temples don't follow Vaishnava Agamas?

Comment: both,  I want the division into (1) vishnu temples not belonging to a vaishnavite sampradaya - it is likely these would not follow vaishnavite agamas (2) vishnu temples belonging to an established vaishnavite sampradaya that do not follow established vaishnavite agamas.

Comment: OK, you should edit your question (both body and title) to make that clear.